# Custom post type from front-end form

Tags: wordpress, notifications, custom-post-type

I want to create a form in the front end and make a custom post type from that form than in the admin I want that post to be as pending post and when I changed the status to canceled or published I want to send an e-mail to the person who submitted the form.

Did anyone get any good tips, plugins or sources that can teach me how to do this?

It’s the last thing I have to do and I’m really stuck.

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not intended for general suggestions or tips. If you have specific difficulties with a task, please construct a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of something you have tried that could be improved.

Comment: You can try to create a form and send to database, off course you will need allow only logged users or a captcha to avoid spam. check this out, https://www.inkthemes.com/how-you-can-easily-create-customized-form-in-wordpress/
after that you need to recover this data into your custom post type 
you can follow this steps http://scottpdawson.com/create-a-database-driven-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/